# Common Denominator of an Array of Arrays

Tags: javascript, python

I'm trying to migrate a Python code to Javascript and I'm facing same issues on my calculations.
I also have no documentation to base on except this code:

```
var commonDenominator = ((myClassMap map (sub) -> sub reduce ((item, denominator = 0) ->  item * perClassMultiplier[$$])) reduce ($$+$)) as Number
```

From what I understand, it's trying to read the `myClassMap` and trying to find the common denominator of everything.

I'm trying to convert but my code is doing a `greatCommonDenominator` and my calculations are wrong in the order of 100, I believe. Maybe I'm wrong...

Entry:

```
myClassMap -> [ [ 1, 150 ], [ 1, 0 ], [ 1.5, 8 ], [ 1.5, 0 ] ]
perClassMultiplier -> [ 1, 1, 1.5, 1.5 ]
```

Code

```
 myClassMap.map(entry => {
                const commonDenominator = greaterCommonDenominator(entry[0], entry[1]);
                if(data.commonDenominator == null | commonDenominator > data.commonDenominator) {
                    data.commonDenominator = commonDenominator;
                }
            });

const greaterCommonDenominator = function(a, b) {
if (!b) {
  return a;
}

return greaterCommonDenominator(b, a % b);
}
```

Any help? I want to make sure the code does the same calculation

Comment: Can you share the Python code you were trying to convert? I don't see any Python in the question.

Comment: `var commonDenominator = ((myClassMap map (sub) -> sub reduce ((item, denominator = 0) ->  item * perClassMultiplier[$$])) reduce ($$+$)) as Number`

Comment: That's not Python. Looks like JavaScript to me, especially with that `var` declaration. I'm not actually sure what language it is, but I know for sure it's not Python.